# form turn to not responding after downloading a file from server

Tags: c#, forms

Its a very weird thing.

I created a client and a server to upload and download files. When uploading I can upload a lot of files without a problem but when I download a file the client for turn to not responding and doesn't show `MessageBox.show("Downloaded");` its the first tie to see this :D.

The code that make the problem when used :

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        String fileToDownload = filePathDownload.Text;


        TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(serverIPDownload.Text, 8880);
        NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
        ASCIIEncoding asci = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] b = asci.GetBytes(fileToDownload + "?");
        byte[] bb = asci.GetBytes("Download?");
        int thisRead = 0;
        int blockSize = 1024;
        Byte[] dataByte = new Byte[blockSize];

        networkStream.Write(bb, 0, bb.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
        networkStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(
            "C:/Users/Laptop/Documents/Downloads/" + fileToDownload, 
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None))
        {
            while (true)
            {
                thisRead = networkStream.Read(dataByte, 0, blockSize);

                fileStream.Write(dataByte, 0, thisRead);
                if (thisRead == 0) break;

            }
            MessageBox.Show("File Downloaded");
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}
```

Thanks. This maybe off topic but its the problem I faced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code appears to be ok, so I suspect the problem is in the Download method you are reading from.

Also, I would personally move the loop termination (`if (thisRead == 0) break;`) before the `fileStream.Write` statement.

And for production code, I would add some sort of timeout limit so that you don't end up in an infinite loop.